# SSIS I need to use primary key values in additional tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am new to SSIS and I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

I need to move data from one database to another. I have written a query that takes data from a number of tables (SOURCE). I then use a conditional split (Condition: Id = id) to a number of tables in the destination database. Here is my problem, I need another table populating which takes the ‘id’ value from the three tables and uses them in a fourth table as attributes, along with additional data from SOURCE. 
I think I need to pass the id values to parameters but there does not seem a way to do this when inserting to ADO NET Destination.

[image: MY SSIS Diagram]

Fourth table will have inserted id values(auto incremented) from table1, table2 and table3.

Am I going about this correctly or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Source goes to 1, 2, 3. You need to know what just got added to 1, 2, 3 to record in some audit table, 4?

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to get the IDENTITY values of rows inserted in a Dataflow destination for use in the same Dataflow.

Probably the way to do what you want to do is to make a fourth branch in your dataflow inserting the columns that you have into the fourth table, and leaving the foreign keys (the ids from the other 3 tables) blank.

Then after the Dataflow, use an ExecuteSQL task to call a stored procedure that populates the missing columns in the fourth table by looking up their ids in the other three tables.

If your fourth table doesn't have the values you need to lookup the ids in the other three tables, then you can have the dataflow go to a staging table that does have those values, and populate the fourth table from the staging table while looking up the ids from the corresponding values.

Comment: Thanks Tab for your example! I am starting to wonder if this would be better achieved as a SQL Agent job instead. I will give your solution a go and see how I get on. Thanks again!